# How to fill RecyclerView Adapter with Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, firebase

I made a lot of research, but I couldn't find any resource how to use Recycler View with `Firebase`(or vice versa)

There is one Firebase list adapter which extends from `BaseAdapter`. I found it in [Firebase Chat application](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat). Here is the [FirebaseListAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat/FirebaseListAdapter.java) class. But the adapter which is used by RecyclerView needs to be extended from `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

How did you overcome this problem? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the moment you will have to provide your own implementation of the RecyclerView.Adapter.

You can use the FirebaseListAdapter for inspiration or roll your own.

Here's a chat app that uses a RecyclerView: https://github.com/thaleslima/Chat-Firebase/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/gdgcampinas/chat_firebase

### Update

There is now a library called [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) that includes a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and much more. I highly recommend that you use that one in your apps or as the basis for an adapter that suits your needs.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the **FirebaseUI-Android**, it is developed by Firebase itself which is quite useful.

The link shown as below.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md