# Can't realize RecycleAdapter to custom ArrayList to get random query result on database

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a database in `Firestore` and `RecycleView` to put the data from it. I send some query to `Firestore` and it get me the result depending on my request. But what, if I want to take 3 random results from the set issued to me on request. That is I get, for example, 20 results and want to take only 3 result each time when I send a request. And each time, it must be random 3 results from this 20?

I was helped to implement the mechanism of selection of 3 random results into the code, but I do not understand how to connect it to my `adapter`.

```
    public class Myactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView mResultList;
    public FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    public com.google.firebase.firestore.Query query;
    public FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Places, PlaceViewHolder> firestoreRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycle_activity);
        mResultList = findViewById(R.id.list_result);

        Boolean l_check1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("1");
        Boolean l_check2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("2");
        Boolean l_check3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("3");
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();  
        if (l_check1) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "1").limit(20);
            query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Places place = document.toObject(Places.class);
                        placesList.add(place);
                    }
                    int placeCount = placesList.size();
                    int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(placeCount);

                    List<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                        randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomNumber));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        } else if (l_check2) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "2").limit(3);
        } else if (l_check3) {
            query = mFirestore.collection("Places").whereEqualTo("colour", "3").limit(3);
        }
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Places> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Places>()
                .setQuery(query, Places.class)
                .build();
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Places, PlaceViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(PlaceViewHolder holder, int position, Places model) {

                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getImage());
            }

            @Override
            public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
                return new PlaceViewHolder(view);
            }

        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }
    class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDetails(Context context, String placeName, String placeImage) {

            final TextView place_Name = mView.findViewById(R.id.text_image_id);
            ImageView place_Image = mView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

            place_Name.setText(placeName);
            Glide.with(context).load(placeImage).into(place_Image);

            place_Name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Card_activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("qwerty", place_Name.getText());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (firestoreRecyclerAdapter != null) {
            firestoreRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

My Place.class:

```
public class Places {
private String image, name;
public Places() { }

public Places(String image, String name) {
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name; 
}
public String getImage() { return image; }
public String getName() { return name; }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your logic for generating the `randomPlaceList` is incorrect as you just generate one Random Number using `new Random().nextInt(placeCount)` and then just keep using it thrice for adding entries to your list.

You should update your logic as follows,

```
...
final int placeCount = placesList.size();
final Random randomGenerator = new Random();
List<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++) {
    randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
}
...
```

See this thread to see how you can fill the `RecyclerView` after you fetch the results from `Firebase`:
[How to fill RecyclerView Adapter with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110108/how-to-fill-recyclerview-adapter-with-firebase)

Comment: it's all work good, as without your changes, but i have 3 identical results each time...@user2004685

Comment: And i take back again 20 results, not 3..@user2004685

Comment: @SpikeJohnson I'm not able to parse the above two comments you made in my mind. Could you please be more clear and specific? I gave an answer to what you asked!

Comment: There I take some `Extra` from another activity and based on this result and checking it in if loop, I make a `query` in Firestore, then from the search sample I take 3 results, grab the "name" and "image" fields and set them in the `RecycleView`. But if the conditions are the same, then the result is the same, just take the first 3 fields from Firestore in order of their placement there and if they fit the conditions, they are displayed in `RecycleView`. I need so that each time, it 3 results will be random.@user2004685 Now, with this changes, absolutely nothing changes..

Comment: Some people told me that this is happening because I am using to create the `options` object a `quer`y which has no constraints. In order to solve this, I need to use in my adapter, the `randomPlaceList` which contains those 3 random items or to restrict this inside the adapter where I am setting the views.@user2004685

Comment: I mean how to make the adapter work not with the model class, but with the already created ArrayList (randomPlaceList). To work with not the 20 records that I received on query, but with 3 randomly selected and entered in the (randomPlaceList)@user2004685