# Recycler view not showing data on activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am developing a app which needs to fetch data from firebase into a recycler view but it is not doing so.
the app runs fine but does not show anything in recycler view portion.

**MainArea.java(onCreate)**

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_rating);
        Email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Fullname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        City=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.City);
        Address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        rating=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rating);
        int s=getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
        DatabaseReference ref=MainArea.FBRA.getRef(s);
        ss=ref.getKey();
        DatabaseReference ref2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(ss);
        ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
                  email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                  fullname=dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                  city=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue().toString();
                  address=dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                  Totalrating=dataSnapshot.child("TotalRating").getValue().toString();
                    rating.setText(Totalrating);
                    Email.setText(email);
                    Fullname.setText(fullname);
                    City.setText(city);
                    Address.setText(address);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError ) {

            }
        });
        myRef2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RatingPosts").child(ss);
        Rview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        Rview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Rview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DisplayRating.this));
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dataget,ViewHolder2> Fbra=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dataget, ViewHolder2>(
                dataget.class,
                R.layout.cardr2,
                ViewHolder2.class,
                myRef2
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder( ViewHolder2 viewHolder, dataget model, int position ) {
                    viewHolder.setAddress(model.getAddress());
                    viewHolder.setPicture(model.getPicture());
                    viewHolder.setRating(model.getRating());

            }
        };
        Rview.setAdapter(Fbra);
     }
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public  static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
     {
         View mView;
         Context ctx;
         public ViewHolder2( View itemView ) {
             super(itemView);
             mView=itemView;
             ctx=itemView.getContext();
         }


         public void setAddress( String address ) {
            TextView Add=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            Add.setText(address);
         }

         public void setPicture( String picture ) {
             ImageView img=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.img);
             Picasso.with(ctx).load(picture).into(img);
         }

         public void setRating( String rating ) {
                TextView rate=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.ratee);
                rate.setText(rating);
         }
     }
```

**dataget.java**

package com.hitachiapp.hitachi.hitachiapp;

/**
 * Created by Mohit Gupta on 23-05-2018.
 */

public class dataget {

```
String Address,Picture,Rating;

public dataget( String address, String picture, String rating ) {
    Address = address;
    Picture = picture;
    Rating = rating;
}

public dataget() {
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress( String address ) {
    Address = address;
}

public String getPicture() {
    return Picture;
}

public void setPicture( String picture ) {
    Picture = picture;
}

public String getRating() {
    return Rating;
}

public void setRating( String rating ) {
    Rating = rating;
}
```

}

**firebase Structure**
[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ieQt.jpg)

Comment: have you tried call notifyDataSetChanged method?

Comment: Were to call that

Comment: Hope this link works https://stackoverflow.com/q/31110108/5028163

Comment: Firebase ui dependency is already included

Comment: Actually app contains 2 recycler view one is working fine but another is not

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: after you set the items to adapter, you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

1 - Ensure that you add the permissions line in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2 - Check your `DatabaseReference`. Try using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RatingPosts")` to confirm is the link is valid or Log the data in the logcat

3 - Ensure that your data model is your database data model. (Your screenshot indicate that the children have more children and your data model shows data types)

4 - Make sure `recycler.setAdapter(adapter);` is called after adapter

5 - Ensure that you call `recycler.setLayoutManager(layout);` before number 4

Your code is not sufficient to debug without the log but this are the common mistakes that people do while using firebase.

Comment: @MohitGupta Your code is not sufficient to debug without the log but this are the common mistakes that people do while using firebase.

Comment: I tried the above solution 
No 2
When i intialize database reference to as in 2 some blank rows are shown 
But when i intialize it to
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RatingPosts").child(ss);
Nothing comes..
ss=key i.e B2WKQY...
what to do now 
@Lucem

Comment: Please help @Lucem

Comment: the only way i can help you is if you clean up your code, Test it on a separate activity with independent values @MohitGupta. Would you like me to inspect it for you?